# Jquery tabs not working or wrong references?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong with this code? Tabs aren't working:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1"><span class="tabs-1">Dados Um</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2"><span class="tabs-2">Dados Dois</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3"><span class="tabs-3">Dados Três</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4"><span class="tabs-4">Dados Quatro</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5"><span class="tabs-5">Dados Cinco</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-6"><span class="tabs-6">Dados Seis</span></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"></div>
    <div id="tabs-4"></div>
    <div id="tabs-5"></div>
    <div id="tabs-6"></div>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();

    $('.tabs-2').bind("click", tabs2);
    $('.tabs-3').bind("click", tabs3);
    $('.tabs-4').bind("click", tabs4);
    $('.tabs-5').bind("click", tabs5);
};

function tabs2() {
    alert("hi");
};
```

And JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/y2FCK/)

Comment: Your `document.ready` is missing a closing bracket. Other than that, where are the `tabsX` functions defined?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I deleted my post - I fixed it in JS fiddle but I couldn't add it to my answer (terrible connection) - I notice Jason managed to post a fixed version anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check http://jsfiddle.net/y2FCK/1/

```
$("#tabs").tabs(); 

$('.tabs-2').bind("click", tabs2);
$('.tabs-3').bind("click", tabs3);
$('.tabs-4').bind("click", tabs4);
$('.tabs-5').bind("click", tabs5);

function tabs3() {
   alert("clicked tab3");
};
```

Added Jquery UI js in fiddle  and also you need to include the same in your project file:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/Aw43k/1/

Looks like the problem with your JSFiddle was that it was missing jQuery and jQueryUI. Also jQuery on ready function is not needed.

```
$("#tabs").tabs(); 

$('.tabs-2').bind("click", tabs2);
$('.tabs-3').bind("click", tabs3);
$('.tabs-4').bind("click", tabs4);
$('.tabs-5').bind("click", tabs5);

function tabs2() {
  alert("hi");
}
```

Comment: The `document.ready` will be needed in your actual Javascript though, just not in jsFiddle, as it adds it for you.

Comment: True. I guess I was getting ahead of myself with just making sure it worked in jsFiddle; darn helpful tools!